# How to prevent "force-attribute-nesting" Sass-Lint warnings when applying CSS properties to specific input elements, along with selects and textarea?

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint, sass-lint

I'm using Sass-Lint in my build system and am getting the warning `Attribute-selector should be nested within its parent Type-selector` when using the following selector:

```
input[type='text'],
input[type='number'],
input[type='email'],
input[type='password'],
select,
textarea {
    color: gray;
}
```

How can this be updated to prevent the warning messages, but also apply the CSS properties to all of these elements? (I obviously don't want to apply the attribute selectors to `select` and `textarea`, but not sure how else to do it without having two separate selectors with duplicate properies?)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, hope will be helpfull.

```
// sass-lint:disable-block no-qualifying-elements force-attribute-nesting
input[type='text'],
input[type='number'],
input[type='email'],
input[type='password'],
select,
textarea {
    color: gray;
}
```